# Does play framework server have rewrite_mode like apache?

Tags: java, playframework

Does play framework server have a rewrite_mode functionality like apache?

That is: how can play generate url like:

```
domain/controller/action/etc... and not 
domain/controller.jsp? etc....
```

Thanks.

Comment: play uses routes which maps requests to controllers, and can take any number of forms. your question isn't so clear.

Comment: Codemwnci answer to what i meen, I agree that Question not clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The routes file handles the incoming request URL and translates that URL into an Action that is executed.

If you do not specify a route in your controller, it is automatically picked up by the "catch-all" route, which translates to

```
/controllername/actionname
```

For more information, the Play documentation has a very clear summary of how the route file functions.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/routes